# How to massively change string capitalization in a table?

Tags: mysql, string-manipulation

I have a project where authors' names have been inserted in all capital letters (ex. JOHN KRAUS, LEONARD MILES, NAOMI DAWSON). Now I need these values in "normal" case (ex. John Kraus, Leonard Miles, Naomi Dawson)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181937/how-to-do-a-proper-case-formatting-of-a-mysql-column) might answer your question. You can find related information by searching for "mysql title case" or "mysql proper case".

Comment: It would be easier to do the task in some other programming languabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mysql` has a mechanism called `cursors` that allows to read all the rows from the table one by one. Detailed description can be found here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

You have to write a stored routine with a cursor loop inside and to place some case transforming logic in it. Useful functions are LOWER(), UPPER(), SUBSTRING() and other text functions described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html